# Select * from a pivot table in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a many to many relation with table users,items and the pivot table user_item and i need to call the query : Select * from user_item where user_id=$user->id in laravel and return the results in json format. I try with

```
$user=User::find(session('user_id'))->items()->get();
return response ()->json($user);
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that?

```
class User extends Authenticatable {
    
    public function items (){
            return $this->belongsToMany ("App\Models\Item", "user_item", "user", "item");
    }
}
```

```
class Item extends Models {
    
    public function users (){
        return $this->belongsToMany ("App\Models\User", "user_item", "item", "user");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you please show the migration file for your `user_item` table?

Answer (score 0):

You can define columns in your pivote table using `withpivot` method

```
public function items (){
        return $this->belongsToMany ("App\Models\Item", "user_item", 
    "user", "item")->withPivot(['column1', 'column2','another_column']);
}
```

to get relation instead of using `get()`, you should use like below:

```
$user=User::find(session('user_id'))->items;
return response ()->json($user);
```

above will give below json result:

```
[{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "PC",
    "pivot": {
        "column1": 1,
        "column2": 4,
        "another_column": "2016-03-03"
    }
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Phone",
    "pivot": {
        "column1": 1,
        "column2": 4,
        "another_column": "2016-03-03"
    }
}]
```

you can also include pivot in use user model using with():

```
$user=User::with('items')->find(session('user_id'));
return response ()->json($user);
```

give json result something like:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "User Name",
    "email": "email@user.com",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null,
    "items": [{
        "id": 4,
        "name": "PC",
        "pivot": {
            "column1": 1,
            "column2": 4,
            "another_column": "2016-03-03"
        }
    },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Phone",
        "pivot": {
            "column1": 1,
            "column2": 4,
            "another_column": "2016-03-03"
        }
    }]
}]
```